# Final Cut Express: Flip a Video Clip

Tags: video, final-cut-express

I'm sure this is trivial to do, but I've yet to find the right filter to Flip a video clip in FCE 4.

For example, see what happens at the 0:42 mark in this video  ([Night Stand HD Pro](http://vimeo.com/14448960))

I see box flips, or page flips, but how can I just flip a single layer around an axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question:

After a lot of searching last night, I found a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eypaRHcriAs) that demonstrated a method to animate the flip of video clips using a free plugin called [MultiSpace](http://idustrialrevolution.com/component/sobi2/?sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=4&sobi2Id=5) from idustrial revolution.